# How to compare the date of content stored in local storage with a database field in syncfusion rich-text-editor?

Tags: persistence, syncfusion, rich-text-editor

I have a richtext bound to a value in the database (from syncfusion).
But I want to use the persistence, in case the user doesn't save his draft or in case his browser crashed ((data stored in the local storage).
So far so good.

Now I'd like to compare the date of the content stored locally vs the date this bound field has been last saved in the database. And depending on this I will show the value in the database or the persistent value saved locally.

Is this something we can achieve? and if yes, how do I get the date of the persistent data?

Any piece of advise would be very welcomed :)

Kind Regards,

Yvan Blancmunier

I'd like to see if we can retrieve the timestamp of data stored in the local storage?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the data persistent in RichTextEditor works based on the local storage mechanism. here, we have passed the key-value pair of date and time while saving the data into the local storage using the unload event to achieve your requirement. Please check the code and sample below,

```
ngOnInit() {
 setTimeout(() => {
  window.addEventListener('unload', function () {
    localStorage.setItem('Date', new Date().toString());
  });
 });
}
```

**Sample**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6pb8hy?file=src%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp.component.ts

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWshe.png)

In the above image, you can see that both the persisted data and date time are stored in the local storage and you can store that date value into your database.